# MPC for a mecanum wheeled model using Drake

Tags: robotics, drake, mpc

I'm new to `MIT Drake`, I was using `CasADi (ipopt)` for a mecanum wheeled model for `MPC`.

In `CasADi`, I can create a symbolic variable for the optimization parameters (i.e., initial state and target state).

Then use it to compute the error in state, how can I get an equivalent functionality in `Drake`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've definitely seen mechanum wheels work in drake, but doing trajectory optimization for them requires some thought.  For most every wheeled robot trajectory optimization, you want to use a minimal coordinates model.  I discuss that briefly in the ballbot example in the notebook associated with http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/acrobot.html

And for formulating your MPC, I would recommend the notes in http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/trajopt.html